# Choose APNG fallback frame

Tags: fallback, apng

By default, browsers without APNG support will display the first frame of the sequence. Is there a way of choosing which frame will be used as a fallback? In most cases, the last frame would make more sense than the first for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can't specify which frame is used as a fallback, but you can tell it to skip the first frame when playing the animation. Then you can add the first frame with whatever you want to display to unsupported viewers.